# Filtering the records

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose i have table WORLD  with columns Country , state and other columns.
I need to filter the records such that

- `Country = 'USA' and STATE = 'LA'` (all other states in USA should come) and
- `Country = 'CANADA' and state = 'ALBERTA'`(all other states in CANADA should come) and
- I don’t want any records with `country = 'GERMANY'` (No states in GERMANY should come)

All those records should not be fetched.

Can you give me the query?

Comment: Please consider taking a regular SQL learning course, because what you ask for are really the basicmost fundamentals of SQL. Such a course will also help you state your SO questions in an exact manner, it will help you understand what you need to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the tricky part here is finding how to express a `WHERE` clause *not* matching some criterion.

You can use [*De Morgan's laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> **"not (A and B)"** is the same as **"(not A) or (not B)"**
>
> **"not (A or B)"** is the same as **"(not A) and (not B)"**.

So the complement of

```
... WHERE (Country = 'USA' and STATE = 'LA') 
          OR (Country = 'CANADA' and state = 'ALBERTA')
          OR (country = 'GERMANY')
```

Is

```
... WHERE (Country <> 'USA' or STATE <> 'LA') 
          AND (Country <> 'CANADA' or state <> 'ALBERTA')
          AND (country <> 'GERMANY')
```

---

If you want to solve that using relational algebra, you are probably looking for [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29). This is expressed in Oracle using the `NOT IN` operator (see [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries006.htm#sthref2290)):

```
SELECT ....
WHERE theID NOT IN (SELECT theID WHERE (Country = 'USA' and STATE = 'LA') 
          OR (Country = 'CANADA' and state = 'ALBERTA')
          OR (country = 'GERMANY'))
```